# Reasons why my C++ Program runs extremely slow/stalls using Visual Studio debugging (F5) and fast/no stalls not using it (Ctrl+F5) in the same config

Tags: c++, julia, visual-studio-2019

It's basically a Hello, World application with all vanilla settings with the addition of one external library and an init to it.  The program takes about 21 seconds to run within Visual Studio using the debugger (F5 or Start Debugging), but runs instantly otherwise.  Happens in Release and Debug.

The library is for the Julia programming language.  I include it's lib and header directory and simply call jl_init(). Half the stall happens before the line is even hit.

From the command line (cmd to the project dir and type x64\myprogram.exe) or Ctrl+F5 it runs instantly.

From Visual Studio using F5 or hitting "Start Debugging" take about 10 seconds to even reach the jl_init() line which is the very first line of the program.  Then another 10 seconds to get through it.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    jl_init(); // takes almost 10 seconds to reach this line, before it even runs.
    printf("Hello, World!\n"); // takes another 10 seconds to reach this line.
    return 0;
}
```

I'm on VS 2019 v142.  Windows 10.  The project is on a local SSD.  I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.  Any ideas?

Edit:
It could be related to loading symbols, but these files are mostly build without symbols though:

'Julia.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Program Files\Julia-1.6.2\bin\libjulia.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

I'll add that I went into Tools>Options>Debugging>Symbols and selected "Load all modules, unless excluded", then added these dlls into the list of excluded modules.  I also unchecked all symbol file location checking in the same dialog.  I don't see any indication in the output or the modules debug window that my changes took effect.  I also tried disabling ALL symbol loading in Tools>Options>Debugging>Symbols by selecting "Load only specified modules" and specifying no modules.  Making these changes didn't help.

I think it's definitely related to dll loading but don't know how.

Edit 2: disabling Tools > Options > Debugging > General “Load debug symbols in external process” made the stall go from 21 seconds to about 12, which indicates it's symbol related.

Comment: Might be worth checking your antivirus.

Comment: On Windows, I configure my Defender settings to ignore Visual Studio and its assortment of executables, and to ignore my source code directory, and to ignore my executable.  Doing that makes my debug sessions about x100 faster.

Comment: I did try adding exclusions to Defender (the only antivirus I have) to no avail

Comment: Back in the day...I recall launching a program in a debugger would trigger the OS to select the Debug Heap for your process, whereas launching normally (Ctrl+F5) would select the much more performant Low Fragmentation Heap.  You could try launching with Ctrl+F5 then Attaching the debugger after your process is running (Attach to process...) if your application is bottlenecking on heap operations (memory allocations).

Answer (score 1):

One of possible issues here is PDB loading.

PDB's are needed to debug libraries, and help debugger resolve callstacks when there are functions from that library in it. In many cases you can debug your app just as well without most of them loaded.

You can disable automatic loading, or set whitelist of modules for which you want to load PDB's following Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019#symbol-file-locations-and-loading-behavior

Comment: The reason I think PDB's are to blame here is since jl_init probably loading some libraries for Julia programming language and visual studio will try to load PDB's at that moment.

Comment: It only downloads them once, though, unless the associated binary changes.

Comment: That download if it happens is very long, that is true. But depending on number and size of libraries the loading itself can take some time. We don't know how many libraries that function will load, it may load many different libraries.

Comment: You will see the libraries wizz past in the Output tab as they are being loaded if you launch the app under the debugger.  It also says whether the corresponding PDB has been found ('symbols loaded'.  Watching that on program load might reveal something.